# Invalid use of group function - How i can use SUM function inside the SUM ? or is there any other way to get same results? Below is my query

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT product_date  dt,account_id, account_name, account_accounttypeID,
    SUM(SUM(invoicedetail_quantity * invoicedetail_price)) cr, 0 dr
FROM product
JOIN invoice_detail ON invoicedetail_itemID = product_id
JOIN invoice ON invoice_id = invoicedetail_invoiceID
JOIN account ON account_id = product_inventoryaccountID 
WHERE invoice_companyID = '49'
    AND invoicedetail_itemtype = 'PR'
    AND invoice_invoicedate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
    AND invoice_status = 1
```

Comment: Why are you using sum(sum(...))?

Comment: why do you want to use sum inside sum function?

Comment: I want to like this SUM(SUM(unit) * price )

Comment: Any reason why there is no GROUP BY clause?

Comment: i want group by with other fields, if i do group by then SUM is not working perfectly. :)

Comment: You cannot use a sum function without a group by. Try restating your question to explain what you are trying to achieve